# type inference removing a seq<'T> for an obj

Tags: f#

Why is `f` inferred to be of type `obj -> int` and not  `seq<'T> -> int` ?

```
  let fseq (o:'T seq) : int = 0                  //val fseq : o:seq<'T> -> int
  let f = match true with                        //f : obj -> int
                  | true ->  fun o -> fseq o
                  | false -> failwith ""
```

That leads to strange message such as the following later

```
  let a : (obj -> int ) list = []
  let a' = f::a  //error yet type inference says f : obj -> int
```

ps : not really a problem, inference always has a limit and it is quite powerful in fsharp, but I am wondering why the type would be unified to obj in here.

Comment: For me this gives a value restriction but does come close to giving the correct type.  What version of F# are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is a typical value restriction.

In f# functions can be generic, not constants. You can solve it as any other value restriction, for example moving the argument to the left side of the `=`:

```
let f o = match true with                    
              | true  -> fseq o
              | false -> failwith ""
```

Regarding the second error it's confusing what you see. The code is not compiling because of the first error but intellisense is telling you another thing.

It's normal, specially when the code is not compiling that intellisense tells you something else, sometimes it infers the correct type but not the compiler, they are not always in sync.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with second part of Your code - `a` is `(obj -> int ) list` while it should be `(obj seq -> int )` since it is type of `fseq` function. The following codes works well.

```
let fseq (o : 'T  seq) : int = 0             
let f = match true with                        
        | true ->  fun o -> fseq o
        | false -> failwith ""

let a : (obj seq -> int ) list = []
let a' = f::a
```

Comment: sorry my question was misleading. I meant to point at the reason why type inference would remove the type (leading to weird error whereby is says cant cons  'a  to 'a list)

Comment: @nicolas, Actually i believe that that definitions of a and a' makes type inference resolving to wrong type - Your a' definition makes type inference  "think" f has to have obj -> int type. If i remove a and a' completely and leave fseq and f only i got Value Restriction error (described well here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx   )